# Click event in bootstrap 3 tabs

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap-3, onclick, jquery-events

I have the following HTML:

```
<div id="channels">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="ul-channels">
        <li class="channel" data-roomid="lobby"><a class="link-channel" href="#lobby" data-toggle="tab">lobby</a></li>
        <li class="channel active selected" data-roomid="test"><a class="link-channel" href="#test" data-toggle="tab">test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I need an event that occurs when switching tabs. Like this:

```
$('.nav-tabs a').click(function (e) {
    alert("Q");
});
```

I tried a lot of options, but I had no success. I will appreciate any help.

Comment: Try `$('.nav-tabs').bind('click', function (e){ ... });` and dont forget the DOM ready handler

Comment: *"As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document."* from http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The final my solution:

```
$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target) // activated tab
})
```

Comment: How can I change this code, so that while on a[data-toggle="tab"]:last one event will fire, but if on any other tabs a different event does.

Comment: @Greg L, I think we should try this:

$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]:last', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target) // activated tab
})

$(document).on( 'shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]:not(:last)', function (e) {
   console.log(e.target) // activated tab
})

Comment: Good.  But how do I also get an event if the currently opened tab is clicked again?

Comment: @Bryce, as I know, show.bs.tab and shows.bs.tab don't allow to perform this task.

Comment: Any idea why given in official guide not working and need to use "document" hear?

Comment: @Nish, Unfortunately, I am not a javascript developer. Therefore, I have no idea about it :(